# flex spring jpa hibernate maven svn

Tags: apache-flex, svn, hibernate, spring, maven

i look for a tutorial or an ebook that gather the use of the following technologies flex spring jpa hibernate maven svn, for the database, it doesn't matter if it's amysql, postgresql or a oracle one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start [Here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/fullstack_pt1.html)[adobe.com] for a tutorial on Flex, Spring, and Hibernate with Maven as a build tool. It's a great walkthrough from Abobe. SVN is a just version control and you can find plenty of tutorials online.